# 2 folders of same name in internal storage of Oneplus3

Tags: file-system

Currently on my phone, i have 2 folders of the same name. The content of both folder shows 0 bytes. EDIT : They are exactly the same. And the subfolders and files are also same with 0 bytes content. When i deleted the 2 folders with same name, then other new folder was seen with the same name of an existing folder. I know it sounds confusing and impossible. But could this be due to storage problem?

I only want to ask, is this a known problem or has this happened with someone else before ?

Comment: What exactly is the name of those duplicate folders? How are you looking at them? I mean which app you are using?

Comment: I am using 'FX file explorer'. Initially it was Whatsapp. Then after deleting 2 folders of Whatsapp, it was Viper4android.

Comment: May be a problem with File Explorer or Media Storage. Filesystems don't support multiple files/folder of identical names in same directory. Try some other explorer or Termux to see directory names.

Comment: @IrfanLatif i checked in termux too. It was still the same. All my pictures in whatsapp folder were gone from gallery.